# Animation in NSCell

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I would like to have a spinner animation(a custom imageset not the default) in some `NSCell`s inside an `NSTableView`. I was able to achieve this by using an object that calculates the correct image and I force update the affected cells to get about 25-30 fps. I'm pretty sure that this is not the way it should work as it will consume a lot of CPU.
Any suggestions how to do this more effectively?

Answer (score 0):

I do this in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath delegate method so when the user touches a cell it adds a spinner to the accessoryView on the right.

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
UIActivityIndicatorView *activityView = 
[[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
[activityView startAnimating];
[cell setAccessoryView:activityView];
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate: [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0.01]];
```

*Note this is for iOS but I assume its very similar for OSX

Comment: Unfortunately it is different for OSX. There is no accessoryView or any view that you can access for this purpose.